# no se muestra grafica completamente en html2pdf.js

Tags: javascript, css, html2pdf

Tengo un componente en Vue 3 que muestra una gráfica de temperatura y humedad. Estoy utilizando html2pdf.js para generar un PDF, pero la gráfica no se ve correctamente en el PDF, excepto si reduzco el tamaño de la ventana del navegador. Aquí está mi código:

```js
const generatePDF = () => {
  const content = document.getElementById("pdfContent");

  // Crear una copia del contenedor original
  const contentCopy = content.cloneNode(true);

  // Crear el contenido adicional (por ejemplo, un título, una imagen y texto adicional)
  const additionalContent = document.createElement("div");

  // Crear la imagen
  const image = document.createElement("img");
  image.src = "/img/logos/osherlogo.png"; // Reemplaza con la ruta de tu imagen
  image.style.width = "130px"; // Ajusta el ancho según tus necesidades
  image.style.height = "60px"; // Ajusta la altura según tus necesidades
  image.style.marginTop = "-5px"; // Ajusta el margen superior según tus necesidades

  // Agregar la imagen al contenido adicional
  additionalContent.appendChild(image);

  // Agregar el título al contenido adicional
  additionalContent.innerHTML +=
    "<h1 style='font-size: 24px; color: blue; text-align: center;'>Historico Temperatura & Humedad</h1>";

  // Obtener la opción seleccionada en los radio-inputs
  const selectedOption = document.querySelector(
    "input[name='radio']:checked"
  ).value;

  // Obtener la fecha actual según la opción seleccionada
  const currentDate = new Date();
  let additionalText = "";

  switch (selectedOption) {
    case "Día":
      additionalText = `Día: ${currentDate.toLocaleDateString()}`;
      break;
    case "Mes":
      additionalText = `Mes: ${currentDate.toLocaleDateString("default", {
        month: "long",
      })}`;
      break;
    case "Año":
      additionalText = `Año: ${currentDate.getFullYear()}`;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  // Agregar texto adicional según la opción seleccionada
  additionalContent.innerHTML += `<p style='color: blue; text-align: center;'>${additionalText}</p>`;

  // Aplicar estilos adicionales al contenido adicional
  additionalContent.style.color = "blue";
  // Agregar más estilos según sea necesario

  // Insertar el contenido adicional al principio de la copia
  contentCopy.insertBefore(additionalContent, contentCopy.firstChild);

  // Otras opciones para la generación del PDF
  const pdfOptions = {
    margin: 7,
    filename: `${additionalText}.pdf`,
    image: { type: "jpeg", quality: 0.98 },
    html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
    jsPDF: { unit: "mm", format: "a4", orientation: "portrait" },
  };

  // Generar el PDF con la copia modificada
  html2pdf(contentCopy, pdfOptions);
};
```

```css
.radio-inputs {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #eee;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  padding: 0.25rem;
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.radio-inputs .radio {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.radio-inputs .radio input {
  display: none;
}

.radio-inputs .radio .name {
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border: none;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  color: rgba(51, 65, 85, 1);
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.radio-inputs .radio input:checked + .name {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

// empieza el css de las fechas

.demo-date-picker .block {
  padding: 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: solid 1px var(--el-border-color);
  flex: 1;
}
.demo-date-picker .block:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.demo-date-picker .container:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.demo-date-picker .demonstration {
  display: block;
  color: var(--el-text-color-secondary);
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.containerTablero {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  margin-left: 7.3%;
}

.tempTitulo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: x-large;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.hum {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.graficaWidth {
  width: 90%;
}

.btnPdf {
  margin-top: 29px;
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="radio-inputs">
        <label class="radio">
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="radio"
            v-model="selectedOption"
            value="Día"
          />
          <span class="name">Día</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio">
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="radio"
            v-model="selectedOption"
            value="Mes"
          />
          <span class="name">Mes</span>
        </label>

        <label class="radio">
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="radio"
            v-model="selectedOption"
            value="Año"
          />
          <span class="name">Año</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="containerTablero">
      <div class="demo-date-picker">
        <div class="container" v-if="selectedOption === 'Mes'">
          <div class="block">
            <el-date-picker
              v-model="fecha"
              type="month"
              placeholder="Elegir mes"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container" v-if="selectedOption === 'Año'">
          <div class="block">
            <el-date-picker
              v-model="fecha"
              type="year"
              placeholder="Elegir año"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container" v-if="selectedOption === 'Día'">
          <div class="block">
            <el-date-picker
              v-model="fecha"
              type="date"
              placeholder="Seleccionar día"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <el-button class="btnPdf" type="danger" @click="generatePDF"
        ><el-icon><Document /></el-icon> &nbsp; Generar PDF</el-button
      >
    </div>

    <div id="pdfContent">
      <p class="tempTitulo">Temperatura</p>
      <div class="center">
        <div class="graficaWidth">
          <div v-if="temSerie[0].data.length > 0">
            <apexchart
              type="line"
              height="350"
              :options="temOptions"
              :series="temSerie"
            ></apexchart>
          </div>

          <div v-if="humSerie[0].data.length > 0">
            <p class="tempTitulo hum">Humedad</p>
            <apexchart
              type="line"
              height="350"
              :options="humOptions"
              :series="humSerie"
            ></apexchart>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

[image: la grafica deberia llegar hasta noviembre]

He notado que la gráfica se ve correctamente en el navegador, pero al generar el PDF, la visualización no es la misma. ¿Alguna sugerencia sobre cómo puedo abordar este problema y asegurarme de que la gráfica se vea correctamente en el PDF?

agradezco cualquier orientación o sugerencia sobre cómo abordar este problema. ¡Gracias!